# Parameter usage on the fly when declaring object

Tags: java, oop

I am asking the user to input the name and his money value like this.
I tried to do this on the fly like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
    players.add(new Player(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: "), getIntInput(players.get(i).name + " enter your amount of money: ")));
}
```

getIntInput is a custom method to get int input.

It should work like this:

> Please enter your name:
>
> Alex
>
> Alex enter your amount of money:
>
> Whatever int...

Can I do this on the fly, or should I traditionally use another for loop to ask for the money?

Comment: IMO, the "on the fly" is unclear. Can you please reformulate your question?

Comment: @Stephan basically I need to use the players name that I declared for the first parameter and pass it to getIntInput (method that promts another Joptionpane to ask for the money)

Comment: @Stephan JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: "), getIntInput(HERE GOES NAME THAT THE USER TYPED FOR THE FIRST PARAMETER + " enter your amount of money: ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding like you are, is asking for troubles and difficulties.

Try to follow these steps:

- Ask name
- Put name in variable
- Ask amount of money
- Put money in variable
- Create Person with name and variable

Instead of trying to do everything in 1 line.

Comment: I know but I was wondering maybe there is an alternative. It is always good to learn something new.

Comment: Learning something bad is not good. Could you expand your question with the problem you are having? For now, I don't see you asking for the amount of money in your application.

Comment: look up to my answer to Stephan. The getIntInput is my custom method to get int. It contains a JOptionPane.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Wesley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35337912/363573), IMO it's the more "*obvious*" and simple way to achieve your goal.

However, I may suggest you the [Builder pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm) here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
    players.add( PlayerBuilder.init().askName().askMoney().create() );
}

public final class PlayerBuilder {
    private String name = "-No name-";
    private int money = 0;

    private PlayerBuilder() {
    }

    public static PlayerBuilder init() {
        return new PlayerBuilder();
    }

    public PlayerBuilder askName() {
         this.name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");
         return this;
    }

    public PlayerBuilder askMoney() {
         this.money = getIntInput(this.name + " enter your amount of money: ");
         return this;
    }

    public Player create() {
         return new Player(name, money);
    }

    private int getIntInput(String msg) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to save some time writing the `PlayerBuilder` class, you can transfer the dirty job to [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html). It will to do it *on the fly* for you...